# How to search for individual rows in multidimensional array then perform calculation for each individual element in certain rows

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I am currently using a table to find corresponding fuel levels in individual tanks in relation to the total amount of fuel the vessel is holding. The vessel currently has 8 tanks and the fuel is distributed accordingly to the amount of total fuel the vessel is carrying. When given a total fuel amount I need to find or populate approximately where the fuel is at in the 8 tanks at that total fuel amount.

I have tried searching through the 2d array to find the corresponding fuel tanks at a given time but with the chart (2d array), I realized I need to use an index for the left most column, (which is the total fuel) and then find the lower bound row and upper bound row. Afterwards I need to find the average of the two rows each individual elements (fuel tanks). I was able to make if statements and hardcore the math, but I know there is a recursive way to search the left column, find the upper and lower bond row of a given fuel amount and find the amount in each fuel tank. So if I was given a target amount of fuel of ie. 194568, I need to find approximately where the fuel is at in the 8 tanks.

```
int main()

const int NUM_ROWS = 22;
    const int NUM_COLUMNS = 9;

    int arr[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLUMNS] = {
    {80000,4500,7500,11700,11700,0,0,0,9200},
    {90000,4500,7500,13800,13800,0,0,0,10800 },
    {100000,4500,7500,15900,15900,0,0,0,12400},
    {110000,4500,7500,18200,18200,0,0,0,13200},
    {120000,4500,7500,20400,20400,0,0,0,14400},
    {130000,4500,7500,22000,23000,0,0,0,16000},
    {140000,4500,7500,22000,26200,0,0,0,19600},
    {150000,4500,7500,22000,29400,0,0,0,23200},
    {160000,4500,7500,22000,32700,0,0,0,26600},
    {170000,4500,7500,23200,35400,0,0,0,28800},
    {180000,4500,7500,25300,37500,0,0,0,30400},
    {190000,4500,7500,27400,39600,0,0,0,32000},
    {200000,4500,7500,29500,41700,0,0,0,33600},
    {210000,4500,7500,31800,44300,0,0,0,33800},
    {220000,4500,7500,31800,44300,0,0,10000,33800},
    {230000,4500,7500,31800,44300,0,3000,15000,35800},
    {240000,4500,7500,31800,44300,0,8000,15000,40800},
    {250000,4500,7500,31800,44300,0,8000,25000,40800},
    {260000,4500,7500,31800,44300,0,8000,35000,40800},
    {270000,4500,7500,31800,44300,0,8000,45000,40800},
    {280000,4500,7500,31800,44300,0,14000,45000,44800},
    {290000,4500,7500,31800,44300,0,18800,46000,49000}, };

    int key;
    cout << "Enter Fuel Amount:";
    cin >>  key;

        if (key >= 80000 && key < 90000)
            {


            cout << "L/R_Ext = " << (arr[0][1] + arr[1][1]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "L/R_ Outbrd = " << (arr[0][2] + arr[1][2]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "L1 R4 = " << (arr[0][3] + arr[1][3]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "L2 R3 = " << (arr[0][4] + arr[1][4]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Forward = " << (arr[0][5] + arr[1][5]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Center = " << (arr[0][6] + arr[1][6]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Mid = " << (arr[0][7] + arr[1][7]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Aft = " << (arr[0][8] + arr[1][8]) / 2 << endl;
            }

            else if (key >= 90000 && key < 100000)
            {
                cout << "L/R_Ext = " << (arr[1][1] + arr[2][1]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "L/R_ Outbrd = " << (arr[1][2] + arr[2][2]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "L1 R4 = " << (arr[1][3] + arr[2][3]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "L2 R3 = " << (arr[1][4] + arr[2][4]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Forward = " << (arr[1][5] + arr[2][5]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Center = " << (arr[1][6] + arr[2][6]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Mid = " << (arr[1][7] + arr[2][7]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Aft = " << (arr[1][8] + arr[2][8]) / 2 << endl;
            }

            else if (key >= 100000 && key < 110000)
            {
                cout << "L/R_Ext = " << (arr[2][1] + arr[3][1]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "L/R_ Outbrd = " << (arr[2][2] + arr[3][2]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "L1 R4 = " << (arr[2][3] + arr[3][3]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "L2 R3 = " << (arr[2][4] + arr[3][4]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Forward = " << (arr[2][5] + arr[3][5]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Center = " << (arr[2][6] + arr[3][6]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Mid = " << (arr[2][7] + arr[3][7]) / 2 << endl;
                cout << "Aft = " << (arr[2][8] + arr[3][8]) / 2 << endl;
            }
    cout << "First row:\n";
    for (col = 0; col < NUM_COLUMNS; col++) {
        cout << arr[0][col] << '\t';
    }

    cout << "Second row:\n";
    for (col = 0; col < NUM_COLUMNS; col++) {
        cout << arr[1][col] << '\t';
    }

    cout << "\n\nSecond column:\n";
    for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
        cout << arr[row][1] << '\n';
    }

    cout << "\n\nThird column:\n";
    for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
        cout << arr[row][2] << '\n';
    }
        cout << "\n\nForth column:\n";
        for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
            cout << arr[row][3] << '\n';
        }

/*etc....
```

I expect the outcome when given a target of 125648 it will search the array and return the fuel in each tank for

```
int LR_Ext;
int LR_Outbrd;
int L1R4;
int L2R3;
int Forward;
int Center;
int Mid;
int Aft;
```

and perhaps assign them to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of repeating the entire `cout` statements in each `if` case, you could first determine an `index` which you can use in display code:

```
int index = 0;

if (key >= 80000 && key < 90000)
    index = 0;
else if (key >= 90000 && key < 100000)
    index = 1;
else if (key >= 100000 && key < 110000)    
    index = 2;
else
    // You should do some check if an invalid key is provided

// Now display    
cout << "L/R_Ext = "     << (arr[index][1] + arr[index+1][1]) / 2 << endl;
cout << "L/R_ Outbrd = " << (arr[index][2] + arr[index+1][2]) / 2 << endl;
cout << "L1 R4 = "       << (arr[index][3] + arr[index+1][3]) / 2 << endl;
cout << "L2 R3 = "       << (arr[index][4] + arr[index+1][4]) / 2 << endl;
cout << "Forward = "     << (arr[index][5] + arr[index+1][5]) / 2 << endl;
cout << "Center = "      << (arr[index][6] + arr[index+1][6]) / 2 << endl;
cout << "Mid = "         << (arr[index][7] + arr[index+1][7]) / 2 << endl;
cout << "Aft = "         << (arr[index][8] + arr[index+1][8]) / 2 << endl;
```